# Django Form Preview - Adding the User to the Form before save

Tags: django-forms

```
class RegistrationFormPreview(FormPreview):
    preview_template    = 'workshops/workshop_register_preview.html'
    form_template       = 'workshops/workshop_register_form.html'

    def done(self, request, cleaned_data):
        # Do something with the cleaned_data, then redirect
        # to a "success" page. 
        # data = request.POST.copy()
        # data['user_id'] = u'%s' % (request.user.id)
        # cleaned_data['user'] = u'%s' % (request.user.id)
        #f = self.form(cleaned_data)
        #f = self.form(data)
        #f.user = request.user


        f = self.form(request.POST)
        f.save()

        pdb.set_trace()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success')
```

As you can see, I've tried a few ways, and that have been commented out. The task is apparently simple: Add the user from request to the form before save, and then save.

What is the accepted, working method here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the user can't be modified, I would say it shouldn't even be included in the form in the first place.

Either way, [using the `commit` argument](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) to prevent the resulting object being saved immediately should work (assuming `FormPreview` uses `ModelForm`):

```
obj = form.save(commit=False)
obj.user = request.user
obj.save()
```

Comment: Thanks insin, right on!
I have a further related question if you'd like to pursue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628132/django-form-preview-how-to-work-with-cleaneddata

best thx.

Comment: @insin What happens if an error is raised by `obj.save()`? This might not be the case most of the time with a simple `request.user` case, but what about more complicated cases. How do you handle validation and error rendering after `save(commit=False)`